# How can i display alert after sending form and reloading page?

Tags: php

As title says, how can i display alert after sending form, and reloading page?

My code looks like:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['add_user'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        if (!empty($username) && !empty($password)) {
            //SQL - Adding user to database
            //And i should reload page, to prevent resending form later
            //But i also want an alert after page reload
        } 
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```html
//functions.php
<?php
    $current_page = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

    function AntiFormResend($alert, $location) {
        $_SESSION["status"] = $alert;
        header("Location: $location");
        exit(0);
    }
?>
```

```html
//index.php
<?php
    require 'functions.php';
    if (isset($_POST['add_user'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        if (!empty($username) && !empty($password)) {
            //SQL - Adding user to database
            $alert = '<div class="alert">Success: User added</div>';
            AntiFormResend($alert, $current_page);
        } else {
            $alert = '<div class="alert">Error: User not added</div>';
            AntiFormResend($alert, $current_page);
        }
    }
?>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <?php
          if (isset($_SESSION["status"])) {
            echo $_SESSION['status'];
            unset($_SESSION["status"]);
          }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution, redirect back to your original form, with a parameter added in the URL like so: `header("Location: /myForm.php?success=true")`.

Then it's as simple as (In myForm.php):

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['success']) && $_GET['success'] === 'true') {
  echo "<script>alert('Success!');</script>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help! I was looking for something that doesn't require changing url. :P